# How can I clear the weight from outsiders vertex when weight painting?

Tags: weight-painting

I can not fix a problem with a vertex to which I can not eliminate the weight of a certain bone. The worst thing is that I can *add* weight, but never *subtract* weight.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

[image: screenshot with a freehand circles highlighting the problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say we have a nice and happy cube

[image]

Oh no they got sick!

[image]

The doctor said that this cube needs to lose some weight and eat healthy paint :D

One way the cube decided to lose weight was to select all the vertices, it set the strenght to 0 and presses <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>  to apply the strenght to all the vertices

[image]

The little cube was surprised how quickly this method was, and so he wondered "is there another method" so he browsed on Google about health diets and found this other method with same results:

Select all the vertices you want to clear their weight, now select the vertex group of the bone that you desire to remove, now click on Remove and it will remove all weight from that bone

[image]

The little cube was very happy and decided to live a healthy life, found love, got married, and had children

[image]

Comment: HAHAHA
THANK YOU VERY MUCH, YOUR METHOD (DIET) WORK PERFECTLY.

AN APOLOGY FOR MY ENGLISH, I DO NOT SPEAK IT NATIVELY AND I AM VERY OUT OF PRACTICE TO SPEAK / WRITE IT, ALTHOUGH I UNDERSTAND IT WELL.
(I HOPE THAT GOOGLE TRASLATOR HELP ME WELL IN THIS :p)

I WILL CONTINUE PRACTICING BLENDER AND MY ENGLISH

P.S.
I LOVE THE HAPPY CUBE STORY

REGARDS

Comment: Google translator did a good job translating :v